# Is there a technique for combining multiple images to create a sharper result?

Tags: terminology, image-processing, superresolution

I've been experimenting with photogrammetry for a while, and the main hurdle I keep tripping over is the clarity (lack thereof) of my images.

Rather than spend a lot of money on a better camera, I'm wondering if there are ways to overcome the inherent imprecisions. One idea I had is to snap the exact same photo several times (from a tripod) and somehow combine those images to refine the accuracy. I'm familiar with focus stacking, and that's not what I'm thinking of (though it might still be helpful in ways I haven't thought of). I'm also not necessarily talking about stitching low resolution images into a higher resolution panorama. In fact, for photogrammetry, the image lens metrics have to be calculable and consistent.

Is there an existing technique for doing something like this, i.e. refining one image with another, or combining many images to create a finer result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely. This is called "superresolution", and we actually have a number of questions and answers on it in the [superresolution](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/superresolution?sort=votes&pageSize=50) tag. There is also a [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superresolution) where you can learn more.

Comment: Turns out, after further investigation, this is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Thanks again ;-)